# Deep copy of objects with List field

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

Deep copy of objects

I need to copy an object to another with same field names. This can be achieved with BeanUtils, but I am looking for deep copy. The objects contain a List of another object and again these 'sub-objects' are similar. I am able to achieve this by partial use of BeanUtils and manual copy.

```
public class MindBO implements Serializable {

    private String mid;

    private String name;

    private List<TagBO> tags;

    /* Getters and Setters */
}

public class MindEO implements Serializable {

    private String mid;

    private String name;

    private List<TagEO> tags;

    /* Getters and Setters */
}

public static MindEO copy(MindBO mBO) {

    MindEO mEO = new MindEO();

    try {
        BeanUtilsBean bub = BeanUtilsBean.getInstance();
        Map<?,?> props = bub.describe(mBO);

        // Remove non-trivial List field
        props.remove("tags");

        // Copy other fields
        bub.populate(mEO, props);

        // Copy List manually
        if(mBO.getTags() != null) {
            List<TagEO> mEOTags = new ArrayList<TagEO>();
            for(TagBO tBO : mBO.getTags()) {
                mEOTags.add(map(tBO));
            }
            mEO.setTags(mEOTags);
        }

    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mEO;
}
```

However, this approach is tedious, error-prone, non-scalable. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: For each of your custom Classes, implement a copy constructor or a copy factory.

Comment: just to mention, if your data is Serializable, dont use List as an interface type, since the Collection interfaces dont extend the serializable interfcae, instead use one of it's implementers, an ArrayList or LinkedList for example